# What is meant by the limit of a Cauchy Sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I understand what a limit is, and I understand what a Cauchy Sequence is, but what is the limit of a Cauchy Sequence?

Comment: Which books or websites have you tried to consult before asking here?

Comment: To be blunt, Google.

Comment: There is no difference between the concept of the limit of a sequence and that of the limit of a Cauchy sequence. The only reason that Cauchy sequences are of particular interest is because all convergent sequences are Cauchy, and in complete spaces like $\mathbb{R}$, all Cauchy sequences are convergent. (Here I assume whatever spaces we're talking about are metric spaces, not merely topological spaces.)

Comment: Why has this question been down-voted? $\qquad$

Comment: I'm glad that someone with 6 fig rep also gets confused by certain downvotes.  Considering some of the questions I've seen downvoted, I thought there was something I was missing.  But this makes me think otherwise.

Comment: Think of "being Cauchy" as a characteristic of a sequence, a bit like "monotone," or "positive." The limit of a Cauchy sequence is the limit of a sequence that is Cauchy, the same way that the limit of a monotone sequence is the limit of a sequence that is monotone, or the limit of an positive sequence is the limit of a sequence which also happens to be positive. (Now, the property of "being Cauchy" has very strong relations with that of "having a limit," on top of that.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy a lot of the "voting to close" seems to be more and more arbitrary, even quite aggressive towards questions like this one by new users, even when the questions are asked in good faith. More worrying, this looks like a self-reinforcing tendency, and sort of reminds me of [this](http://www.wisdompills.com/2014/05/28/the-famous-social-experiment-5-monkeys-a-ladder/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ of real numbers. Then, the limit of the sequence is $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$, provided that this limit exists. In particular, if $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, then it will always converge (i.e., have a limit), since all Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ converge.

Answer (score 1):

The "limit" of a Cauchy Sequence is the same as the "limit" of any sequence.  The number "L" is the limit of sequence "$a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots,a_n, \ldots$" if and only if, for any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist $N$ such that if $n> N$ then $|a_n- L|< \epsilon$.  That is, you can get as close to $L$ as you like by taking $n$ large enough.